# Python3: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to combine pandas to retrieve the values of a number of tables in the fixtures, but on the extraction I'm also willing to include the href tags contained within the tables, however I come across an error:

The code is:

```
import numpy as nd
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://fcf.cat/calendari/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-1'
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'calendaritable'})[0]

print(df)

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

links = []
for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    trs = tr.findAll("td")
    for each in trs:
        try:
            link = each.find('a')['href']
            links.append(link)
        except:
            pass

df['Links'] = links
print (df.to_string())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting a complete example - this is really helpful! So we can get a better sense of the issue, can you post your error, including the full stack trace? See this guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some great tips.

Comment: Can you also explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? When I run your code, I get a dataframe with shape (8, 7) and a list `links` which is length 1112. You can't create a column in the dataframe `df` with a different length than the other columns. Is there a reason why you're trying to add the list of links as another column rather than just keeping it as a variable?

Comment: You are doing `pd.read_html(...)[0]` to get the first table, but you are discarding 29 other tables that `read_html` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will certainly try to explain better. The websites in fact contains 32 tables. I want to concentrate in tables 1 to 30 as these contain the fixtures. The idea was extract the links in one and then make a loop to do the same for the other 29.  Pandas only extracts the text and not the links. Ultimately I want to extract all the information and export it to an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I have written and does the job for me:

```
import numpy as nd
import pandas as pd



url = 'http://fcf.cat/calendari/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-{}'
hoja = 'grup-{}'


xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Resultados.xlsx')


for i in range(1,19):
  converturl = url.format(i)
  # print(url)
  dfResultats = pd.read_html(converturl, header=0)
  numgrupo = hoja.format(i)
  tablelen = len (dfResultats)
  tablelen = tablelen - 1 
  strrow = 0
  strcol = 0
  for x in range (1,tablelen):
   df = dfResultats[x]
   df.to_excel(xlwriter,sheet_name=numgrupo, index=False, startrow=strrow , startcol=strcol)
   strrow = strrow + 9

xlwriter.close()
```

The idea was to enhance the code to include the hrefs on the excel sheet, as this includes to link to the game details which I need to extract later.

Answer (score 0):

This script will get all information from tables, including the links:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://fcf.cat/calendari/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

out = []
for tr in soup.select('.calendaritable tbody tr'):
    t = tr.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')
    a = tr.select_one('.calendaritablehover a')
    jornada = tr.find_previous('th', {'colspan': '4'}).get_text(strip=True)
    jornada_date = tr.find_previous('th', {'colspan': '3'}).get_text(strip=True)

    if len(t) == 4: # there's result
        out.append({'Team 1': t[0], 'Team 2': t[3], 'Goals 1': t[1], 'Goals 2': t[2], 'Jornada': jornada, 'Jornada date': jornada_date, 'Link': a['href'] if a else ''})
    else:
        out.append({'Team 1': t[0], 'Team 2': t[2], 'Goals 1': '', 'Goals 2': '', 'Jornada': jornada, 'Jornada date': jornada_date, 'Link': a['href'] if a else ''})

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
                             Team 1                    Team 2 Goals 1 Goals 2     Jornada Jornada date                                               Link
0                 CATALONIA, U.B.,A            EUROPA, C.E.,B       0       1   Jornada 1   06-10-2019  http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-pr...
1         FUNDACIO P. CE. JUPITER,A  ESCOLA PIA SARRIÀ S.E.,A       1       0   Jornada 1   06-10-2019  http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-pr...
2             Pª BARC. CINC COPES,A         MONTAÑESA, C.F.,A       1       0   Jornada 1   06-10-2019  http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-pr...
3            Pª BARC. BARCINO, CE,A        Pª BARC. ANGUERA,B       0       3   Jornada 1   06-10-2019  http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-pr...
4              DIAGONAL CLUB ESP.,A          SISTRELLS C.F.,A       8       2   Jornada 1   06-10-2019  http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-pr...
..                              ...                       ...     ...     ...         ...          ...                                                ...
235            DIAGONAL CLUB ESP.,A        Pª BARC. ANGUERA,B                  Jornada 30   31-05-2020                                                   
236               MONTAÑESA, C.F.,A    Pª BARC. BARCINO, CE,A                  Jornada 30   31-05-2020                                                   
237           Pª BARC. CINC COPES,A  ESCOLA PIA SARRIÀ S.E.,A                  Jornada 30   31-05-2020                                                   
238       FUNDACIO P. CE. JUPITER,A            EUROPA, C.E.,B                  Jornada 30   31-05-2020                                                   
239  L'HOSPITALET, CENTRE ESPORTS,B         CATALONIA, U.B.,A                  Jornada 30   31-05-2020                                                   

[240 rows x 7 columns]
```

And produces `data.csv`, screenshot from Libre Office:

[image]

Comment: WOW!!! that is amazing. I will now need to sit down and try to understand what is the logic behind. Basically as I'm just starting with python and web scrapping, is that you have used beautifulsoup to collect the information and then build a data frame with pandas to export all the information. I will need to try and modify the script as I need to iterate through groups 1 to 18 in the url. This way I will collect all the fixtures for all groups